# Deleting a table row in object oriented programming

Tags: javascript, oop

I started learning OOP in JavaScript at school and I have to do my homework in OOP. It is a shopping list, one fills in a product and price and that is put into an array, the array its contents are put in a table in HTML. The list also has got delete buttons for every product, I have thought about using `this` in JavaScript, as I am working in OOP, but I am sceptic because of the scope.

The idea is that one clicks "verwijder" on the webpage (EDIT: in the corresponding row) and the table row is gone. I have thought about using `this` but also about dynamically updating the table after removing the selected row from the array.

Who can advise me about what to do and how to do that correctly?
I have uploaded my JavaScript here: http://jsfiddle.net/hNAZ9/

Comment: This one should be migrated on codereview.

Comment: Ah, I will delete my question here and migrate, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to study oop in javascript (and you are allowed to use frameworks), my suggestion is to learn a framework like http://knockoutjs.com/ . The separation between view/html interaction code and js object modeling code will make you life much easier. Here is an example reimplementation of your fiddle, using knockout: http://jsfiddle.net/kaGzz/3/

I think it's a lot clearer what the objects are doing:

```
var Item = function(product, price, parentArray){
    var self = this;
    self.product = ko.observable(product);
    self.price = ko.observable(price);    
    self.deleteItem = function(){
        parentArray.remove(self);
    }
}

var ShoppingList = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.currentProduct = ko.observable();
    self.currentPrice = ko.observable();
    self.items = ko.observableArray();
    self.addItem = function(){
        self.items.push(new Item(self.currentProduct(), self.currentPrice(), self.items));
    }        
}


var shoppingList = new ShoppingList();
```

Comment: I can't use frameworks at this moment, as we are supposed to learn basic JavaScript OOP first.

Comment: Well, even so, it would be a good idea to have your object code completely separate from the interface-binding code.

Comment: I have done so, but I changed it to be easily compatible with JSFiddle.